# Cannot set property of undefined with PouchDb when calling a function

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'd like to return values with the find module with PouchDb

I can't return values with the find function and PouchDb

If i call the function 'loadLists' i have this error :
TypeError: Cannot set property 'lists' of undefined

```
public lists;

loadLists(culture, code_agresseur) {

    PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite'));
    this.epiphyt= new PouchDB('epiphyt', {adapter: 'cordova-sqlite'});     

                    // Retrouver les protocoles nationaux

                    return this.epiphyt.find({
                    selector: {
                      ProtocoleCultures: {
                        //"ZAK+"
                        $regex:  culture+'+'

                        },
                    LigneOrganismevivantcode: code_agresseur


                    },
        fields: ['ClasseValeurqualitativecode','ClasseValeurqualitative']

                    }).then(function (res) {console.log(res.docs);

                         this.lists= res.docs;

                        }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    });
                   } 

         // Calling the function 

            this.loadLists('ZAK',8888');
```

Comment: Use arrow functions for callback `function (res) {console.log(res.docs);

                         this.lists= res.docs;

                        }` use `(res)=>{}`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you've supplied, there's no surrounding class.
Assuming there is, declare the function as an arrow function instead so that 'this' refers to that class' instance.

```
loadLists = (culture, code_agresseur) => {
 // code //
};
```

Also use arrow functions within that function.

Otherwise, if it's not within a class, just prepend the code above with the 'const' and that should probably also work.